# Flatapak Skype webcam & audio input & output issue

Tags: sound, skype, webcam, flatpak

I am unable to setup audio & camera on skype.
Skype webcam & audio input & output issue with the permission.

I tried with command line
`flatpak override --user com.skype.Client --socket=pulseaudio`

I just installed flatseal & i am new to it.

I allowed but still not working.
[image]

**The Issue**

[image]

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with xfce & flatpak latest.